# Extracting Formula from String

Tags: c#, .net

I have to extract all variables from Formula

[Fiddle for below problem](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mNmIGZ)

> eg. (FB+AB+ESI) / 12
>
> Output {FB,AB,ESI}

Code written so far

```
var length = formula.Length;
            List<string> variables = new List<string>();
            List<char> operators = new List<char> { '+', '-', '*', '/', ')', '(', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
            int count = 0;
            string character = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                if (!operators.Contains(formula[i]))
                    character += formula[i];
                else
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(character))
                        variables.Add(character);
                    character = string.Empty;
                    count = i;
                }
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(character))
                variables.Add(character);
            return variables;
```

> Output of the Method is {FB,AB,ESI} which is correct

My problem is where Varaible contains numeric field i.e

> eg. (FB1+AB1)/100
>
> Expected Output : {FB1,AB1}
>
> But My method return {FB,AB}

Comment: yes bcoz i want to remove numbers also from the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it with Regular Expressions.

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"([A-Z])\w+");

        List<string> matchedStrings = new List<string>();
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches("(FB1+AB1)/100"))
        {
            matchedStrings.Add(match.Value);
        }
```

This will create a list of strings of all the matches.

Answer (score 2):

If variable's names *must start* with

```
   letter A..Z, a..z
```

and if variable's names *can contain*

```
  letters     A..Z, a..z
  digits      0..1
  underscopes _
```

you can use regular expressions:

```
  String source = "(FB2+a_3B+EsI) / 12";

  String pattern = @"([A-Z]|[a-z])+([A-z]|[a-z]|\d|_)*";

  // output will be "{FB2,a_3B,EsI}"
  String output = "{" + String.Join(",", 
    Regex.Matches(source, pattern)
      .OfType<Match>()
      .Select(item => item.Value)) + "}";
```

In case you need a *collection*, say an *array of variable's names*, just modify the Linq:

```
  String names[] = Regex.Matches(source, pattern)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(item => item.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

However, what is implemented is just a kind of naive tokenizer: you have to separate "variable names" found from function names, class names, check if they are commented out etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have changed your code to do what you asked, but not sure about the approach of the solution, seeing that bracket and operator precedence is not taken into consideration.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string formula = "AB1+FB+100";
        var length = formula.Length;
        List<string> variables = new List<string>();
        List<char> operators = new List<char>{'+', '-', '*', '/', ')', '('};
        List<char> numerals = new List<char>{'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

        int count = 0;
        string character = string.Empty;
        char prev_char = '\0';

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            bool is_operator = operators.Contains(formula[i]);
            bool is_numeral = numerals.Contains(formula[i]);
            bool is_variable = !(is_operator || is_numeral);
            bool was_variable = character.Contains(prev_char);

            if (is_variable || (was_variable && is_numeral) )
                character += formula[i];
            else
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(character))
                    variables.Add(character);
                character = string.Empty;
                count = i;
            }

            prev_char = formula[i];
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(character))
            variables.Add(character);

        foreach (var item in variables)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Maybe also consider something like [Math-Expression-Evaluator (on nuget)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Math-Expression-Evaluator/)

Answer (score 1):

Without regex, you can split on the actual operators (not numbers), and then remove any items that begin with a number:

```
public static List<string> GetVariables(string formula)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(formula)) return new List<string>();

    var operators = new List<char> { '+', '-', '*', '/', '^', '%', '(', ')' };

    int temp;
    return formula
        .Split(operators.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Where(operand => !int.TryParse(operand[0].ToString(), out temp))
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, just optimize the code as you want.

```
       string ss = "(FB+AB+ESI) / 12";

        string[] spl =  ss.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string final = spl[0].Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Trim();
        string[] entries = final.Split(new char[] {'+'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        StringBuilder sbFinal = new StringBuilder();
        sbFinal.Append("{");
        foreach(string en in entries)
        {
            sbFinal.Append(en + ",");
        }
        string finalString = sbFinal.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
        finalString += "}";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is an interpreter.

I can't give you the whole code but what I can give you is a head start (it will require a lot of coding).

First, learn about [reverse polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

Second, you need to learn about [stacks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Third, you have to apply both to get what you want to interpret.